# Rails hooks - `deliver.action_mailer` not firing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, instrumentation

I'm trying to add some logging / auditing to ActionMailer in a Rails app, and I'm trying to hook into the `deliver.action_mailer` hook in an initializer like so:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe 'deliver.action_mailer' do |_name, _start, _finish, _id, payload|
  # Do stuff here
end
```

However, when I run my tests and run `MyMailer.mailer_method.deliver!` the hook never gets fired. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In the test environment the emails are not send, but they are stored in an array

> # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
>    # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
>    # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
>   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

You can write the test like:

```
subject { email.deliver_now }

it 'sends an e-mail' do
  expect { subject }.to change { ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.count }.by(1)
end
```

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking to test. I'm fine with knowing if a mail is sent, but I want to test the code that should be running when the `deliver.action_mailer` hook gets fired. It did inspire me to check if it was because the hook wasn't firing with a `test` delivery method, but even with my production delivery method, it's still not getting fired